# YII - CDetailView: link to another page

Tags: yii

In CDetailView, how do I link a give value to another page? Say I have a book that is member of a book category, e.g. Science Fiction. The book details page displays the following data:

```
Book title: Dune
Author: Frank Herbert
Category: Science Fiction --> link
```

Science Fiction should be a link to `/category/view`, like in the following code, which doesn't work for me:

```
array(
    'label' => 'Category',
    'value' => $model->category->name,
    'urlExpression'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("category/view", 
        array("cid"=>$data->category_id))',
    'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
),
```

I'm getting the impression that urlExpression does not work with CDetailView. It is a property of class CLinkColumn (» CGridColumn » CComponent), so I'm on the wrong track here. What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView

Comment: where did you get urlExpression ?

Comment: i think that you should be on a listview, and this list should contain a link to a detail list

Comment: even if you are already on a details view, you still have relations and the model is loaded; so ... you have everything; just try

Comment: Relations work, but displaying a URL is something else for me right now. I'm relatively new with YII and these frameworks in general, so it's a lot of trial and error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$this->widget('CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'title',
    'author',
    array(
        'name'=>'Category',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>CHtml::link('Link Title', 'url'),
    ),
    ...
```

Comment: For 'Link Title' you can use `$model->category->name`, and for 'url' you can use `array('category/view', 'id'=>$model->category_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing **CDetailView** and **CGridView**.

*urlExpression* is a **CLinkColumn** attribute, and CLinkColumns are used in CGridViews's columns attribute.

[CDetailView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView#attributes-detail) only has an *attributes* attribute.

I guess you could generate your url in the *value* attribute and use *type = raw* to display it

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a way to get it to work, following the proper way. I use CDetailView because of a tutorial, not for any special reason. So I could use CGridView if that would solve the problem. Using your raw option is probably not the preferred way. This is a learning project for me, so I prefer to learn it the right way.

Comment: @rxt, in this case using a raw value is perfectly acceptable.